# Are there any near-production system configuration management frameworks written in functional languages (i.e., Haskell, erlang, etc.)?

Tags: configuration, configuration-management

Similar to Cfengine2/3, Puppet, Chef.

Definitely interested in purity, nondeterminism, idempotency and conflict detection.

*Note* [Cross-posted](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6516/is-there-a-practical-sigh-system-configuration-management-framework-written-in) due to the nature of the question not falling neatly into any particular domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Not yet, however here are some early projects:

Python: kokki, cdist

Perl: Thorium

:UPDATE:

The most major development is an equivalent and better solution:  Fixing package / management (which is to handle conflict resolution and allow for side-by-side.

NixOS is *the* ZFS of configuration management.

salt is old news, not impressed.  Look for ZeroRPC implementation from dotcloud btw.

Comment: NixOS unfortunately doesn't seem stable enough. :'(